# Suma en mysql da NULL en lugar de cero

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, null, sum

Utilizo la siguiente sintaxis en un procedimiento almacenado mysql:

```
SELECT @sumhaber := SUM(impmodes)
FROM movgrl
WHERE RTRIM(haber) = @xcodcta
AND tipop='CM';
```

Los valores del campo o columna `impmodes` son `CERO` para TODOS los registros de la tabla.
La variable `@sumhaber` toma valor `NULL`, cuando debería tomar valor `CERO`.

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

**Nota:** la misma sintaxis aplicada a un campo con uno o más valores distintos de `CERO`, arroja resultado correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que la **función sum** devolverá **null** si no hay filas o si existe al menos un valor **null** entre los valores que se están sumando. Para solucionar este problema puedes usar la **función coalesce** la cual convertirá el valor **null** en **0** o cualquier otro valor que definas:

```
select 
 @sumhaber := coalesce(sum(impmodes), 0) 
from movgrl 
where rtrim(haber) = @xcodcta and tipop='CM';
```

Resumiendo si la suma es **null**, se convertirá en **0** y la **variable @sumhaber** almacenará el valor **0**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Funciona bien. Ahora agrego:
He revisado los campos numéricos de mi tabla mediante la sintaxis:
SELECT count(*)
FROM movgrl 
WHERE impmodes = "NULL";

Esta sintaxis me informa que hay campos numéricos con valor NULL en algunas de las filas (distinta cantidad de filas para cada campo numérico).
Cuando exhibo, en mysql workbench, estos registros mediante la sintaxis:
SELECT * FROM movgrl 
WHERE importe = "NULL";
son mostrados con valor CERO.
Sigue en el siguiente comentario...

Comment: He probado, sin éxito distintas sintaxis para reemplazar los valores NULL por CERO.
Esto me obliga a contemplar la existencia de estos valores NULL en toda sintaxis que incluya el tratamiento de campos numéricos. Ignoro el motivo por el que algunos valores definidos como CERO, son guardados como NULL ¿Tienes alguna consideración al respecto? Gracias

Comment: @Rafael Para saber si hay nulos debes poner where campo is null, y para sustituir esos nulos por cero bien podrías hacer un update, update tabla set campo = 0 where campo is null

Comment: @Rafael si la respuesta te fue útil te agradecería la marcaras como aceptada y si lo consideras, también puedes darle un voto, gracias